# How to replace metatag description using views argument?

Tags: 7, meta-tags, views

I'm having trouble while trying to use views arguments for replacing metatags description.

In the view title you can easily add the view argument for example "Blog posts in category %1" so the "%1" is the first argument and it's replaced in the view title, but it does not work for metatags.

For example I want the description of the metatag to say "Blog posts about %1 in example blog"

Is there any way so that view argument works for metatags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in the available tokens for the metatags while configuring the view, I can access the url arguments with this token [view:url:args]